# I want to find Biggest Changerate in the prices of coins

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, math

i want to find biggests changerate in the prices in my coins data

like if SDT oldprice is 1.00 and
new price is 1.02 = 2%
and  if it was the biggests changerate in the coins my script should printing it

but the script dont working
it only keep give me same coin

```
const math = require('mathjs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
get()
async function get() {
  const response = await fetch("https://trade.kucoin.com/_api/currency/prices?base=USD&targets=&lang=en_US");
  const coin1 = await response.json();
  const olddata = coin1.data
  const tokens = Object.keys(olddata)
  const oldprice = Object.values(olddata)
  get1()
  async function get1() {
    const response = await fetch("https://trade.kucoin.com/_api/currency/prices?base=USD&targets=&lang=en_US");
    const coin2 = await response.json();
    const newdata = coin2.data
    const tokens = Object.keys(newdata)
    const newprice = Object.values(newdata)
    function findLargestDifference() {
      var large = null;
      var index = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < oldprice.length; i++) {
        var change = tokens[i].newprice / oldprice[i].oldprice;
        if (change > large) {
          large = change;
          index = i;
        }
      }
      console.log(tokens[index])
      return tokens[index];
    }
    findLargestDifference()
  }
}
```

here how data looks https://prnt.sc/19syjjg

Comment: What do you understand (or not understand) about what's going on with your code?  Did you try debugging it?  What did you discover?  Why are you stuck?  What happens when you run it?  What are you expecting?  What data does it receive from those requests?  (And you'll want to edit and indent your code to improve readability.)

Comment: in data i get coins names and prices I need to compare oldprices with newprices
and detecting the bigger changerate 
i have than 300coins
like if MLK coin price is 1$ in oldprice data in the newprice data price is 1.02 
and if it the bigger changerate it is MLK 
my script should print (DETECTED MLK)

but my script just keepin print the last coin in my data

Comment: here how data looks
https://prnt.sc/19syjjg

Comment: If you edited your question to make the code an actual runnable snippet, then you could demonstrate exactly the behaviour you describe with sample data.  I think it would be worth your effort to improve the question in this way.

Comment: Minimally, you don't even use the return values of your functions or await your async calls.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing on lines 3 & 10. Are you calling the methods there? Are those meant to be comments?

Comment: Please do not upload code, errors or sample data as _images_.  [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: line 3 and 10
i calling the functions

Comment: i not understand you good
what is need to fix in my code